# Erro ao instalar requirements do rvm

Tags: ruby

Esse erro ocorre para as duas coisas que tentei: 1 - instalar ruby e a partir disso, instalar rvm requirements.

```
Error running 'requirements_debian_libs_install gawk libreadline6-dev libyaml-dev sqlite3 autoconf libgdbm-dev libncurses5-dev automake libtool bison libffi-dev',
showing last 15 lines of /home/larissa/.rvm/log/1461870549/package_install_gawk_libreadline6-dev_libyaml-dev_sqlite3_autoconf_libgdbm-dev_libncurses5-dev_automake_libtool_bison_libffi-dev.log
is only available from another source

E: Unable to locate package gawk
E: Unable to locate package libreadline6-dev
E: Unable to locate package libyaml-dev
E: Unable to locate package sqlite3
E: Package 'autoconf' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package libgdbm-dev
E: Unable to locate package libncurses5-dev
E: Unable to locate package automake
E: Package 'libtool' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'bison' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package libffi-dev
+ return 100
+ return 100
Requirements installation failed with status: 100.
```

Alguem tem alguma solucao para isso?

Obrigada.

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente seu `/etc/apt/sources.list` está com repositórios quebrados.

Tente:

```
sudo apt-get install gawk libreadline6-dev libyaml-dev sqlite3 autoconf libgdbm-dev libncurses5-dev automake libtool bison libffi-dev
```

E veja o resultado.